# Can't boot from USB- FDD and I need to get it back to HDD

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, iso, format

Hello I am running ubuntu 17.04 at the moment I am used to format my usb-falsh drive with Winusb and install windows with no problem and I am doing it for years . today my bother wanted to use windows again and i told him to burn the iso image when I back I have no idea how did he turn the usb-HDD into USB-FDD , I read that has nothing to do with the formatting operation though I found a problem same to mine  in link below

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226392

is there anyway I can possibly getting this flash drive 16GB to be detected as HDD in boot menu
i read in some sites that linux Ubuntu doesn't support booting from FDD only HDD 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is there anyway I can possibly getting this flash drive 16GB to be
>   detected as HDD in boot menu

That will be dependant on whether or not the BIOS supports booting from USB (FYI it won't show up as a HDD, there would be a listing for USB)

Now, if the BIOS is old enough that it doesn't support booting from USB, there's actually a workaround to get it booting from USB:

1. Make sure that you've properly burned the ISO to the flash drive with the Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool. (Yeah the name says Win7 but it works for Win10 too)
2. Download the [PLOP boot manager zip file](https://download.plop.at/files/bootmngr/plpbt-5.0.15.zip) and extract it to a location of your choice.
3. After extracting the ZIP, you will find that one of the files extracted is an ISO. Burn that to a blank CD.
4. Boot the computer from that CD you just burned.
5. Insert the USB drive into a USB 2.0 port (do not use a 3.0)
6. Scroll down to the USB option in PLOP and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I will try that thank you for your reply 
My laptop is Lenovo B5400 so the bios supporting the usb booting and I have done it dozen of times